# Starting automatically another tomcat instance when one goes down

Tags: apache, tomcat

- I am working on a Spring-MVC application and using Tomcat to deploy
  it. I looked up on net how to create a custom maintenance site when
  tomcat is down. It involves using Apache2 in the front and relaying
  requests to and fro tomcat, and the maintenance site can be put on
  Apache2. Seemed like a lot of hassle just for a webpage when tomcat
  is down.

  - For this reasons, I created a small project and deployed it in
    another instance of tomcat as ROOT.war.
  - I would just like to know if there is any way, I can bring the
    maintainance tomcat instance online when production is down.

Here is my server.xml of production for viewing :

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" compression="force" compressionMinSize="1024" 
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="443" URIEncoding="utf-8"
 compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/ javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript"/>


<Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="200" compression="force"
              compressionMinSize="1024" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false"  sslProtocol="TLS"
               keystoreFile="my-keystore.jks" keystorePass="password" URIEncoding="utf-8"
 compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/ javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript"
/>
 <Connector port="8010" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="443" URIEncoding="utf-8"
 compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/ javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript"
/>
```

Any help would be nice. Thanks a lot.

Comment: if the ROOT.war is different from the base url, then how would it be acts as maintainence tomcat instance.

Comment: @anuraggupta  I don't know what you mean by base url, but when I stop the production server and start manually the maintenance server, I see the maintenance page. Both the tomcats are on same server, different directories. In both I am deploying using ROOT.war.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good option used in high availability of application but not sure you would need that.

1. ran 2 tomcat in 2 separate ports always. one is production server and another maintainence server.
2. install haproxy so all request goes from here to the production server port.
3. when haproxy verifies that the port is down or the server not responding go to maintainence port tomcat instance.

in this way, the maintainence activity can be done without any issues. and due to some issues the prod server goes down it automatically call maintainence tomcat instance.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that? I am checking it out already, but if you have expertise in that, it would be really helpful...Thanks a lot.. :-)

Comment: install haproxy in the server and set up the basic functionality . for this specific case impl this link is a good help.
http://serverfault.com/questions/473445/haproxy-switch-only-in-case-of-server-down

if some issues setting it up, let me know.

Comment: I checked the link, but it presumes that I have 2 servers. I don't. I have one single server and I have turned off maintenance instance of tomcat right now.

Comment: i am assuming you have to make up both instance on different ports . and mark these 2 ports in haproxy.cfg

Comment: If I use non-standard ports, then I see those ports in browser...so it looks like domainname.com:standardPortNumber

Comment: nah, haproxy will listen to port 80 and further redirects it to different port. so externally it'll never be known that the content is served from different port.